# Changing location of a walk cycle keyframe

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I'm facing a simple problem:
When I copy-pasted my walk cycle, the locations of the keyframe don't change so it looks like a reset.

How can I add (3.2m on the Y axes) to all the copy pasted key frame ?

I guess it's with the Graph editor but I never used it before.
Any pieces of advice would be very welcome !

Thank you,
V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess you must have keyframed the armature's location itself. What you need to do is open the *Graph Editor*, unfold the *Object Transforms* tracks, select the track that you need to change (probably *X* or *Y Location*), press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide all the other tracks (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to bring them back later) and move the curve on the *Graph Editor* X or Y axis. It will only work if the duplicated action is a simple copy and not a linked duplication, in that case you need to click on *New Action* in the Dope Sheet.

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you !